# How to define a Monad for a function type?

Tags: scala, monads, tail-recursion, scala-cats, parser-combinators

I am trying Cats for the first time and am using Scala 3, and I am trying to implement a set of parser combinators for self-pedagogy, however; I am stuck on the definition of the `tailRecM` function for Monad.  I have managed Functor and Applicative just fine.

I have defined my type in question as a function such that:

```
type Parser[A] = (input: List[Token]) => ParseResult[A]
```

with corresponding return types as:

```
type ParseResult[A] = Success[A] | Failure 
case class Success[A](value: A, tokens: List[Token])
case class Failure(msg: String, tokens: List[Token])
```

My current definition of `tailRecM` is as follows:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def tailRecM[A, B](init: A)(fn: A => Parser[Either[A, B]]): Parser[B] =
  (input: List[Token]) => 
    fn(init)(input) match {
      case f: Failure => f
      case s: Success[Either[A, B]] => s.value match {
        case Right(b) => Success(b, s.tokens)
        case Left(a) => tailRecM(a)(fn) // won't compile 
      }
  }
```

If I attempt to build I get `"Found: Parsing.Parser[B] Required: Parsing.ParseResult[B]"` for `tailRecM(a)(fn)`

The issue as far as I can tell stems from the fact that my type in question `Parser[A]` is a function type and not simply a value type?  I attempted to ameliorate the issue by modifying the `tailRecM` recursive call to `tailRecM(a)(fn)(input)` but then this is obviously not stack safe, and also will not compile.

How can I resolve this issue, and more broadly, how can I implement the Monad typeclass for function types in general?

Comment: First, consider whether it even *makes sense* for your `Parser` to have a `flatMap` method. If your attempt to parse some tokens returns another parser, what is that new parser expected to do? In [my own experience implementing a Parser type](https://github.com/dylemma/xml-spac/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/io/dylemma/spac/Parser.scala) I found that it *didn't* make sense for Parser to have a `flatMap`, so instead of `Monad`, I implemented an `Applicative`.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify that I'm talking about `flatMap` while you're talking about `tailRecM`, the Monad implementation provides a `flatMap` method in terms of the abstract `tailRecM`. Essentially `Monad` is all of the capabilities of `Applicative`, *plus* the ability to `flatMap`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to make `tailRecM` itself tail-recursive; you need to define a tail-recursive helper method

Here's how the `cats` library implements `tailRecM` for `Function1`

```
  def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(fn: A => T1 => Either[A, B]): T1 => B =
    (t: T1) => {
      @tailrec
      def step(thisA: A): B =
        fn(thisA)(t) match {
          case Right(b)    => b
          case Left(nextA) => step(nextA)
        }
      step(a)
    }
```

This is because monadic recursion is a form of *mutual* tail-recursion, where two methods flip back and forth calling each other. The scala compiler can't optimize that. So instead we inline the definition of the monadic part rather than calling `flatMap` or another method

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `input` again to the `tailRecM` call

```
tailRecM(a)(fn)(input)
```

because `tailRecM(a)(fn)` returns a `Parser`, but you need the `ParserResult` from that returned `Parser`, as you already did in all other cases.